# How can I say "I want one of each kind" in Japanese?

Tags: phrase-requests

I remember a trip I did to Japan (it's a magical place) back in 2007 when my Japanese was not as rusty as it is now. In Kyoto I had the chance to buy a *meron pan* from a stall in a park. The fact is, he had many types of bread and I wanted to say him that I wanted one piece of each type. But I could not get with the proper way to say that.

So, 11 years after :-) I go to Google Translate and I come up with the following:

> それぞれの種類の1つ ください

So is that sentence correct? Is there any shorter way to say this?

Comment: それぞれの種類 **を** 1つ **ずつ** ください

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 「それぞれの種類{しゅるい}**の**1つ ください。」
>
> So is that sentence correct?

No, it is not.  That second 「の」 is both incorrect and unnatural.　「それぞれの種類**の**1つ」 just does not make much sense.

Most commonly, we would say:

> 「全{ぜん}種類**を**一個{いっこ}**ずつ**ください。」
>
> 「それぞれ**を**一個**ずつ**ください。」

In informal speech, the 「を」 will often be omitted.